# Running a "match" between two different sets of data

Tags: r, dplyr

I have two different datasets.

The first is called `people` and is structured as such:

```
people <- structure(list(userID = c(175890530, 178691082, 40228319, 472555502, 
                                  1063565418, 242983504, 3253221155), bio = c("Living in Atlanta", 
                                                                              "Born in Seattle, resident of Phoenix", "Columbus, Ohio", "Bronx born and raised", 
                                                                              "What's up Chicago?!?!", "Product of Los Angeles, taxpayer in St. Louis", 
                                                                              "Go Dallas Cowboys!")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                          -7L))
```

The next is file called `location` and is structured as such:

```
location <- structure(list(city = c("Atlanta", "Seattle", "Phoenix", "Columbus", 
                                  "Bronx", "Chicago", "Los Angeles", "St. Louis", "Dallas"), state = c("GA", 
                                                                                                       "WA", "AZ", "OH", "NY", "IL", "CA", "MO", "TX")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                             -9L))
```

What I am trying to do is run a "match" against the `bio` field in the `people` dataset where it matches the string against the `city` field in the `location` dataset.

While in theory I could just do something like:

```
mutate(city = str_extract_all(bio, "Atlanta|Seattle|Phoenix|Columbus|Bronx|Chicago|Los Angeles|St. Louis|St. Louis|Dallas"))
```

That won't actually work in practice because I'll be working with way more data and far more possible cities, so it can't be something hardcoded. I am looking for an output that is structured as such:

```
complete <- structure(list(userID = c(175890530, 178691082, 40228319, 472555502, 
1063565418, 242983504, 3253221155), bio = c("Living in Atlanta", 
"Born in Seattle, resident of Phoenix", "Columbus, Ohio", "Bronx born and raised", 
"What's up Chicago?!?!", "Product of Los Angeles, taxpayer in St. Louis", 
"Go Dallas Cowboys!"), city_return = c("Atlanta", "Seattle, Phoenix", 
"Columbus", "Bronx", "Chicago", "Los Angeles, St. Louis", "Dallas"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

The idea would be that it goes through each row in `people$bio` and "matches" it against all the possibilities within `location$city` and creates a new dataframe called `complete` that has the fields `userID` and `bio` from the `people` dataset along with a new column called `city_return` which gives us the matches we're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)
people %>%
  separate_rows(bio) %>%
  left_join(location, by = c("bio" = "city")) %>%
  filter(!is.na(state))
```

This mostly works, but two problems:

"Atlana" not matched to "Atlanta" but might be possible with `fuzzyjoin` but likely will yield false positives.

Not matching to Los Angeles since this only matches by single words. See below for an approach for two-word city names. You could run each of these and combine

```
# A tibble: 6 × 3
      userID bio      state
       <dbl> <chr>    <chr>
1  178691082 Seattle  WA    # two places mentioned for this user
2  178691082 Phoenix  AZ    # two places mentioned for this user
3   40228319 Columbus OH   
4  472555502 Bronx    NY   
5 1063565418 Chicago  IL    
6 3253221155 Dallas   TX
```

If we want to catch two-word cities, we could do something like this:

```
left_join(
  people %>% tidytext::unnest_ngrams(bio, bio, n = 2),
  location %>% tidytext::unnest_ngrams(bio, city, n = 2) %>%
    filter(!is.na(bio))) %>%
  filter(!is.na(state))
```

Result

```
Joining, by = "bio"
     userID         bio state
1 242983504 los angeles    CA
2 242983504    st louis    MO
```

You could `bind_rows( [first code], [second code] )` to get the full output.

Comment: Ah I'm sorry the Atlanta mistake was just a dumb typo on my part. You don't need to worry about accounting for it. I've edited the question to reflect that change.